# AngularJs vs Laravel. What to pick?

Tags: angularjs, http, laravel-5, phalcon, cassandra-2.0

I am developing a web, iOS and Android app simultaneously.

I have setted up phalcon that connects to Cassandra database and it is used for an API gateway.

All requests are HTTP and nothing connects directly to Cassandra everything is filtered in Phalcon developed app.

Now, I have to consider the login behind the dashboard and the way to develop a fast and scalable user interface.

What to choose for better development and of course safety; Laravel or AngularJs?

Comment: How can you even compare the two? Angular is a frontend framework, while laravel is used on backend. These two are solving different problems and can be used together.

Comment: while it is correct, that direct comparison of front end / back end technologies is not possible working through the answers and comments helped me to clarify the situation

Answer (score 5):

AngularJS is a front end framework and Laravel is a backend framework, comparing them is like comparing apples to bicycles.

Seriously though:
Authentication and database access are fundamentally backend procedures. The framework used to manage the business logic around this are frameworks that run on the server itself, and typically expose a web server and API calls. PHP is one of those languages and is not run in the browser (client) or on any native mobile system (ios/android). Laravel is a framework built around server side PHP to help with these procedures.

The client is the actual browser or mobile phone that is connecting to the back end services through http requests and manages the user experience and UI. AngularJS is a front end javascript framework built for the browser.

If this is news to you, you need to learn a lot before you dig into laravel and angular. Good luck!

Comment: So where I am ought to use Laravel and where to use AngularJs?

Comment: I've updated my answer